# How to compare items in an array and only keep a single instance of the duplicates - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, filtering

I have a large array of Wordpress posts, each item is a basic object which looks like the following:

[image]

This array with contain duplicated objects sharing all the same values including the id. Now that I have my data I would like to parse it and only keep items where there is more than one instance of the object in the array(or more than one instance of the id key value).

So for example if I had an array which looked like this

```
[
     { id: 1, name: 'hello world' },
     { id: 2, name: 'other post' },
     { id: 1, name: 'hello world' }
]
```

I would like to only keep a single instance of the duplicate objects. So my function would return the follow:

```
returnOnlyDuplicates(array)
^ returns => [{ id: 1, name: 'hello world' }]
```

I am stuck on this filtering out "only duplicate" part of this task. I am trying to avoid just using for loops and iterating over everything as that can be very time consuming so I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Currently this is what I have but it doesn't do any sort of filtering, `$parsedResults`just returns the exact same array as `$allResults` after everything is done

```
  $allResults = [{data}, {data}, {data}];
  $parsedResults = [];

  foreach ($allResults as $item) {
     $isFound = false;

     foreach ($allResults as $compare) {
        if ($compare->ID == $item->ID) {
           if ($isFound === false) {
              $isFound = true;
           } else {
              array_push($parsedResults, $item);
           }
        }
     }
  }

  return parsedResults;
```

Answer (score 0):

Group your objects by id.

```
foreach ($allResults as $object) {
    $grouped[$object->id][] = $object;
}
```

Filter out any groups with only one item.

```
$duplicates = array_filter($grouped, function($group) {
    return count($group) > 1;
});
```

Take the first item from each group for the result.

```
$result = array_map('reset', $duplicates);
```

Note that because `array_filter` and `array_map` preserve keys, the keys in `$result` will be the object ids.

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t test it but you may try this:

```
function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) { 
    $temp_array = array(); 
    $i = 0; 
    $key_array = array(); 
    
    foreach($array as $val) { 
        if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) { 
            $key_array[$i] = $val[$key]; 
            $temp_array[$i] = $val; 
        } 
        $i++; 
    } 
    return $temp_array; 
   }
```

And use it like:

```
$allResults = unique_multidim_array($allResults,'id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to save some memory and only keep an array as lookup and use `array_filter()` to reduce the array to the duplicates;

```
<?php

$posts = [
    ['id' => 1, /* more values */],
    ['id' => 2, /* more values */],
    ['id' => 1, /* more values */],
    ['id' => 3, /* more values */],
    ['id' => 1, /* more values */],
    ['id' => 3, /* more values */],
];

function get_duplicates($array) {
    $seen = [];

    return array_filter($array, function ($v) use (&$seen) {
        $identity = $v['id'];
        if (empty($seen[$identity])) {
            $seen[$identity] = 1;
            return false;
        }
        ++$seen[$identity];
        return $seen[$identity] == 2;
    });
}

$duplicates = get_duplicates($posts);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem:

```
$countObjectFound = [];
$duplicatedObjects = [];

foreach ($allObjects as $object) {
    if (empty($countObjectFound[$object->id])) {
        $countObjectFound[$object->id] = 0;
    }

    $countObjectFound[$object->id]++;

    if ($countObjectFound[$object->id] == 2) {
        $duplicatedObjects[] = $object;
    }
}
```

The part below is only to avoid `undefined offset` NOTICE error:

```
    if (empty($countObjectFound[$object->id])) {
        $countObjectFound[$object->id] = 0;
    }
```

So, if you consider it's a problem, you can remove this part.